# Lightning Input inside aura iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, aura-id

I have a situation where i have multiple lightning:inputs written inside aura:iteration. I JS controller i am trying to find the input by using Component.find(),but i came to know component.find will not work inside aura:iteration and will return undefined 2 time. So i used event.getSource().

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.customerDocumentsList}" var="customerDocs">
            <div aura:id="StaticDiv" class="slds-box" style="background-color:White;">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!customerDocs.IsDeferredDocument__c == false}">
                    <lightning:layout class="slds-grid--vertical-stretch" horizontalAlign="left" multipleRows="true">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!or(customerDocs.RecordTypeName__c == 'Deferred',  customerDocs.RecordTypeName__c == 'Invoice' ) }">
                            <lightning:layoutItem  padding="horizontal-small" largeDeviceSize="{!v.lDevice}" mediumDeviceSize="{!v.mDevice}" smallDeviceSize="{!v.sDevice}" size="12">
                                <!--<span style="color:red;" class="required">*</span>-->
                                <lightning:input name ="Invoice no" aura:id="InvoiceNo" label="Invoice no" required="true"
                                                 pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Please enter Alphanumeric Values Only"
                                                 value="{!customerDocs.Invoiceno__c}" disabled="{!v.invoicenoMismatch}" />
                                <ui:inputCheckbox label="Invoice Document Missing " value="{!v.invoicenoMismatch}"/>
                            </lightning:layoutItem>
                        </aura:if>

                        <aura:if isTrue="{!or(customerDocs.RecordTypeName__c == 'Deferred',  customerDocs.RecordTypeName__c == 'Invoice' ) }">

                            <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small"  largeDeviceSize="{!v.lDevice}" mediumDeviceSize="{!v.mDevice}" smallDeviceSize="{!v.sDevice}" size="12"> 
                                <lightning:input name ="Invoice Engine no." aura:id="InvoiceEngineno" required="true" label="Invoice Engine no." pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Please enter Alphanumeric Values Only" 
                                                 value="{!customerDocs.InvoiceEngineno__c}" disabled="{!v.invoicenoMismatch}"/>
                            </lightning:layoutItem> 
                        </aura:if>
//JS controller
createDiscrepancy : function(component,event,helper) {
        console.log('fdsaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
        var invoiceChasis = event.getSource();
        var invoiceEngineNo = event.getSource();
        var invoiceNo = event.getSource();

 invoiceEngineNo.reportValidity();
                    invoiceNo.reportValidity();  
                    invoiceChasis.reportValidity();
```

Here still it is giving me error saying `invoiceEngineNo.reportValidity()` is not a function. I have pasted the code which is only useful not entirely.

I have gone through multiple posts but nothing worked out.Attaching the screenshot of the error.
event.getSource() should work here donno what iam doing wrong!!!

Issue solved due to below code changes.

```
    if(!$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(invoiceNo)){
                            invoiceNo = helper.fetchAuraCmp(component, invoiceNo);
                            invoiceNoValue = invoiceNo.get("v.value");
                        }
//Helper method
fetchAuraCmp : function(component, cCmp) {
        if(!$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(cCmp.length) && cCmp.length > 0){
            //invoiceChasisValue = invoiceChasis[0].get("v.value");
            return cCmp[0];
        }
        else if($A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(cCmp.length)){
            //invoiceChasisValue = invoiceChasis.get("v.value");
            return cCmp;
        }
    },
```

Please help.[image]

Comment: There's not enough code here to really help you, and you're definitely barking up the wrong tree. component.find should work just fine, as long the DOM is finished rendering.

Comment: Component.Find() will not work in case of aura:iteration. when lightning input is inside iteration it will not find tts auraLid in 2nd,3rd iterations. However it is now solved.

Comment: I have checked the length of the data because i was getting array.

Comment: Changed the code to working one

Answer (score 1):

The code is quite ambiguous. There can be many issues. The one that I think is you cannot call a controller method from another method. Try helper methods.
To call a helper method use: `helper.method(component,event,helper);`

Comment: I am not calling any controller method from another method FYI. Please have a look at code one more time.

Comment: As the error now depicts, can you show us the reportValidity() method? Also in lightning, you cannot call one method from another one directly like that. you need to use helper.methodName().